# PHP copy all object properties to this

Tags: php, properties, this, assign

I have an object in PHP, of the type `MyObject`.

```
$myObject instanceof MyObject
```

Now, in the `class MyObject`, there is a non-static function, and in there, I use the reference to "me", like `$this`, but I also have another object there.

Is it possible, without doing `$this = $myObject`, to achieve more or less the same effect, like something of the sort `set_object_vars($this, get_object_vars($myObject))`?

Comment: What do you mean "*use the reference to 'me', like `$this`*", are you aliasing `$this` in the method?

Comment: I think your question needs a little review. Even if we had a set_object_vars() function would that be really the same effect? You would be copying the object, not referencing it. See copying vs referencing in PHP for more.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. _'I use the reference to "me", like `$this`'_ - especially. Maybe this is what your looking for, maybe it is not: [PHP Clone class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. I did not need the same reference, only the properties had to be the same.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
<?php

class MyObject
{
    public function import(MyObject $object)
    {   
        foreach (get_object_vars($object) as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }   
}
```

Will do what you want I guess, but you should be aware of the following:

1. `get_object_vars` will only find non-static properties
2. `get_object_vars` will only find accessible properties **according to scope**

The **according to scope** part is quite important and may deserve a little more explanation. Did you know that properties scope are **class dependent** rather than **instance dependent** in PHP?

It means that in the example above, if you had a `private $bar` property in `MyObject`, `get_object_vars` would see it, since you are in an instance of a `MyObject` class. This will obviously not work if you're trying to *import* instances of another class.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think if that! Now, I only need to copy the properties to the instance, the static properties are irrelevant ^^

Answer (score 1):

@Geoffrey Bachelet we can improve this:

```
class MyObject
{
    //object or array as parameter
    public function import($object)
    {   
        $vars=is_object($object)?get_object_vars($object):$object;
        if(!is_array($vars)) throw Exception('no props to import into the object!');
        foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }   
}
```

The difference is here that you can pass **an ordinary array (hashtable)** as well as an object. Think in example about some data coming from the database.