# How to Auto Cast Database Object to $this (Class) Properties in PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

I've been developing my own framework from scratch until there are column updates here and there so I need to add some repetitive additional code lines to cast the database object in a model.

```
class Student
{
  public $id;
  public $name;

  public function setById($id) {
     ... // PDO $stmt

     // Manual casting works fine but not easy to maintain
     // $student = $stmt->fetchObject();
     // $this->id = $student->id;
     // $this->name = $student->name;

     // So, I'm trying to do auto cast, but $this cannot be re-assign.
     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Student');
     $this = $stmt->fetch(); // Error: Cannot re-assign $this
  }
}
```

Is there any native syntax to do this or it should be done by custom function?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8713088/4205384)?

Comment: Or `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $this);` Never dont it but it looks promising

Comment: @RiggsFolly 'Error Class name must be a string'

Comment: Hmmm not according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php#62048

Comment: @El_Vanja That foreach part works like a charm! I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry my bad, I still tested with `FETCH_CLASS` not `FETCH_INTO`, but still, it has to be stored as an instance, which if I set it to this, I'll get 'cannot re-assign $this'.

Comment: Combination of RiggsFolly and El_Vanja answer is the best, I use it on my code. Thank you both of you.